# why can't I delete this Active Directory object?

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I'm having trouble restoring a DC to replication status.  Somehow it past its tombstone timeout limit.  Anyway I've tried `repadmin /removelingeringobjects` and was not able to remove the offensive AD objects.  Using the Windows Server *Event Viewer* and looking through the `1988` errors, I found that there are only actually two entries left causing problems with replication.

Using sysinternals ADexplorer, I located them both in the AD hierarchy, but I got a "Syntax" error when trying to delete one, and the other, located in `CN=Deleted Objects,DN=DomainDNSZones,DC=domain,DC=com`, didn't even have an option to delete (grayed out).

I then moved to Powershell, where I was able to delete the first object using `Remove-ADObject -Identity blah-blah-blah`.

However, the second object won't go away.  Here's my syntax:

`Remove-ADObject -Identity blah-blah-blah -IncludeDeletedObjects`

The result I get it:

```
Remove-ADObject : The requested delete operation could not be performed
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-ADObject -Identity "blah-blah-blah" -IncludeDeleted ... + 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (blah-blah-blah:ADObject) [Remove-ADObject], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8398,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADObject
```

Now going back to ADexplorer, I checked the Properties and the Security tab of this object, and the tab says:

`The requested security information is either unavailable or can't be displayed`

I'm certain this has something to do with the problem.  I don't have permission to delete the object because... it doesn't have permissions?

Any idea where I can go from here?